# find where file is in umbraco media section using id

Tags: umbraco

I have a file being picked up externally which I've been told has been deleted by the author.

If I go into the Media section on the server I can find the folder with the id 343565 which has the "deleted" file in it.

There is a deep folder tree in our Media section when using the Umbraco backend, is there an easy way to search in the back end using the 343565 id to find it so I can check whether it has been deleted?

It would be useful to know how to do this in v7 too (if it is different) as I will be upgrading to v7 soon

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, that id doesn't relate to the media id.

If you are using v6 or v7, you can use Examine to search the for folder id in the umbracoFile field.

1. Go to the Developer section
2. Select the Examine Management tab
3. Open the Internal Search under the Searchers section
4. Paste this into the search box: umbracoFile:/media*343565*
5. Select the Lucene Search radio button
6. Search

That should bring up the media node and from there you can get the id, path, etc